# How to compress a folder to .ngz

Tags: compression, gzip

I like to think of myself as reasonably computer and google literate (I'm OK ar searching the web). However I've recently had the need to compress into .ngz format and for the life of me I can't find a program that will allow me to compress into that format. I can open the files with 7zip, but it wont allow me to create an ngz archive. Any help appreciated.

Comment: ngz doesn't ring any bells… it's probably gzipped *something*; try using `gzip` to decompress it then use `file` to try to figure out what the contents are.  If you can get a name for the format it should provide a good starting point for more googling.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a gzipped [cpio](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/) file. Try `cpio -i < whatever.ngz`. It will automatically recognize the gzip compression and decompress it, as well as extract the archive. `cpio -oz < list > archive.ngz` will make a new archive given the list of files in `list`.